# Execute C# application in PHP

Tags: c#, php, web-applications

I am new to PHP and I am trying to run a c# application I've developed, from my PHP project. The app is local and is on the same machine as the server.
I should only be able to execute the app (preferably run it in background), since it's output is printed in a separate file which I access in my website.

Is there any way to run the app from my website ? I've tried to use `echo exec(...)` but it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like:

```
<?php
function _exec($cmd)
{
   $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
   $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0,false);
   echo $cmd;
   return $oExec == 0 ? true : false;
}

_exec("yourprogram.exe");
?>
```

More info at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Also the user running the web server will need elevated permissions.

Comment: Can we pass parameter to the .exe file that the C# application can use? Thanks.